# Mathematics of doodling and the winding number

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry

So I was reading the American Mathematical Monthly Feb 2011 (Volume 118, number 2), and in particular, I was interested in Ravi Vakil's article about mathematics of doodling. There is a question I cannot prove (or find the proof of anywhere).

First, here is the definition of the doodle (quoted from the article):

"Informal deﬁnition. I walk around the outside of X counterclockwise, sticking my
right hand out and marking the path with a marker. By a remarkable coincidence, my
arm has length precisely $r$ . We call the resulting doodle $N_r(X)$."

For any convex polygons or closed curves with the maximum winding number of $1$, we have that $Perim(N_r(X)) = Perim(X) + 2r\pi$ and $Area(N_r(X)) = Area(X) + rPerim(X) + r^2\pi$.

In general, for any closed curve, whose winding number is $q$, the $Perim(N_r(X)) = Perim(X) + q(2r\pi)$ and $Area(N_r(X)) = Area(X) + rPerim(X) + q(r^2\pi)$.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to prove the fact: "for any closed curve, whose winding number is $q$, the $Perim(N_r(X)) = Perim(X) + q(2r\pi)$ and $Area(N_r(X)) = Area(X) + rPerim(X) + q(r^2\pi)$." Or explain why the winding number has such an effect on the Area and Perimeter formula for $N_r(X)$.

(Reference: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/monthly116-129-vakil.pdf pp120-122).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Also, what do you think about the "cool fact"? Theorem 3. The average length of the shadow of a convex region of the plane, multiplied by , is the perimeter. Is this a well-known fact? How could we prove it?

Comment: Note that (depending on the precise definition) these formulas will almost certainly fail if $r$ is so big that different parts of the diagram start to interact.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem is one of the easiest applications of Frenet formulas for planar curves and can be found in differential geometry textbooks.

Some minor corrections: First, $q$ is usually called "turning number" rather than "winding number". (The winding number is how many times a curve goes around a marked point; the turning number is how many times its *velocity vector* goes around the origin.) The turning number equals the integral of the curvature divided by $2\pi$. Second, as others noticed, $r$ should not be too large if the curvature attains negative values. More precisely, the result holds true for $r<1/\max(-\kappa)$ where $\kappa$ denotes the curvature.

The proof goes as follows. Let $t\mapsto s(t)$ be an arc-length parametrization of the original curve and $V(t),N(t)$ its Frenet frame. Then the $r$-shifted curve is parametrized by
$$
 s_r(t) = s(t) - rN(t) .
$$
Then the velocity of $s_r$ is given by
$$
 s_r'(t) = V(t) + r\kappa(t)V(t) = (1+r\kappa(t)) V(t) 
$$
because $s'=V$ and $N'=-\kappa V$ by Frenet formulas. Then
$$
 Length(s_r) = \int |s_r'| = \int |1+r\kappa| = \int (1+r\kappa) = Length(s) + r\int\kappa = Length(s) + 2\pi q r .
$$
The area formula is obtained from the length one by integration.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is fairly straightforward in the polygonal case, and I'd wager that the general case follows from the polygonal case.

Let $c(t)$ be a polygonal curve whose maximal winding number is $q$, and assume it has winding number $q$ around the origin.  As you move along a line segment in $c$, you will trace out another line segment of exactly the same length.  When you hit a corner, you will rotate in place until you are facing in the direction of the next line segment, and so you will trace out a circular arc of radius $r$ whose angle agrees with the angle of the curve at that corner.  The "polygonal Gauss-Bonnet theorem" asserts that the winding number of a polygonal curve is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ times the sum of the angles (with the right orientation).

So to compute the perimeter of the doodle, notice that the line segments in the doodle have total length $Perim(c)$ since each segment in the doodle corresponds to one in $c$ of the same length.  At each corner we get a contribution corresponding to the angle at that corner times $r$, for a total contribution of $2\pi r q$.  Area can be computed in a similar way: movement along line segments adds $r$ times the length of the line segment to the area for a total contribution of $r Perim(c)$, and the corners yield a total contribution of $\pi r^2 q$.

Comment: I suppose we need to assume that the curvature of the curve never changes sign, as was guaranteed by the convexity assumption in the case where the winding number was 1.

Comment: Cool, thanks. But I am still confused with something like the figure 8. (see picture of the doodle around 8 in the link). What if the doodle goes "inside" the curve as in the picture? I am having a hard time seeing how your answer would apply in that case. (because whenever the doodle is "inside" the curve, the winding number goes down).

Comment: Yeah, that sort of example is why I added the restriction that the curvature doesn't change sign.  The problem isn't with the winding number - we only care about the winding number of the original curve, not the doodle.  The problem is that the path made by the marker is too complicated when you hit a corner where you have to turn by more than 180 degrees.  I'm not sure what the resolution is (or, come to think of it, if I even believe the formula in such cases).

Comment: Out of curiosity, we may also look at the following: Suppose the curvature changes sign, but if it does, it stays above -1/r, so the corresponding radius of curvature is greater than r. In this case, we do not need to doodle `backwards'. It seems likely to me that the formulas still hold (but the proof by polynomial approximation would not work as polynomial approximation has negative infinite curvature now). It would seem that the direct `write the line integral' approach applies.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for area (or I should say volume form), is always true up to within an error of size $o(r)$. The geometry (boundary, curvature, etc.), only comes into play when you try to write down the second-order correction term.

In fact you can define the boundary measure (aka perimeter) of sets that don't have boundary using that formula. It is the so-called *Minkowski perimeter*. More formally, let $M=(M,d)$ be a metric space equipped with the sigma-algebra of Borel sets, and let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $M$. For any measurable $X \subseteq M$, define

$$
Perim_\mu(X) := \mu^+(X) := \liminf_{r \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\mu(N_r(X)) - \mu(X)}{r},
$$
where $N_r(X) := \{x \in M \mid d(x,m) \le r,\text{ for some }m \in M\}$ is the $r$-thickening (or "doodle") of $X$. Note that $M$ (or $X$) doesn't have to be a 2-dimensional object and the metric $d$ can be very general.

The function  $X \mapsto Perim_\mu(X)$ has all properties you'd expect of a reasonable notion of perimeter. This function is the main object of study in isoperimetric problems.

In your particular case of planar "doodling", $M$ is the euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$, $\mu = dx_1dx_2$, and $X$ is the region bounded by a closed curve.